# Webview Android - Not showing Menu of the website

Tags: android, webview, menu

[Not showing menu in android app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YrJ2.png)
In chrome and other browser it shows properly as below
[Chrome showing proper menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TRb6.png)

everything is enabled Dom, Javascript - code snippet as below.

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.setWebViewClient(new Browser_Home());
webView.setWebChromeClient(new ChromeClient());
webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Your are setting WebViewClient two times

Comment: `layout_width` and `layout_height` should be set to `match_parent`, do you have these attributes set like this?

Comment: It too depends on the website
Can you try in browser with changed aspect ration to mobile screen ?